# keyUp Not Fired in LibGDX Applet on OSX

Tags: java, macos, applet, libgdx, lwjgl

`InputAdapter#keyUp` never seems to be called when my LibGDX game is running as an applet on OSX, in either Firefox or Safari.

The same code works when running as a desktop app, and also works fine in Chrome on a Windows 7 VM. I've put debug logging into my `InputAdapter` subclass, and I can see `keyDown`s get fired, but never `keyUp`s.

Any ideas?

Comment: Show some Code where it's fired or we need a big glas marble.

Comment: What's to show? It's an event driven by the user's input device. The LibGDX framework call my implementation directly, and I can tell that my `InputAdapter` is registered correctly as I can see the logging happening on `keyDown`.

Comment: show the event listeners...  We cant help you if you dont show any code and just explain what the problem is. That would be just newsagent.